# Ajax submitting form doesn't reload page but doesn't post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Help, I am really not familiar with ajax and I wanted to submit a form without reloading the page. Using the codes below, it didn't reload but it certainly didn't post or didn't even call the ajax function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

//this submits a form
    $("#post_form").on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "post.php",
               data: $("#post_form").serialize(),
               beforeSend: function() {
                   $('#input_process').html('Loading');
               },
               success: function(data) {
                   $('#input_process').html(data);
               },
               failure: function(){
                    $('#input_process').html('Failed');
               }

            })
    })
})

</script>
```

And here is the html form codes

```
<div id="input_process"></div>
                    <div id="story_post_input">
                        <form name="post_form" id="post_form" action="" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="story" />
                            <input type="text" name="post_title"/>
                            <textarea name="userpost"></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" name="post_submit" value="post" id="post_submit_button"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div id="shout_post_input">
                        <form name="post_form" id="post_form" action="" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="shoutout" />
                            <input type="text" name="userpost"/>
                            <input type="submit" name="post_submit" value="shout" id="post_submit_button"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div id="image_post_input">
                        <form name="post_form" id="post_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="file" name="post_image">
                            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="image" />
                            <input type="text" name="userpost"/>
                            <input type="submit" name="post_submit" value="upload" id="post_submit_button"/>

                        </form>
                    </div>
```

And here is the post.php code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['userpost'])){
        $post_type = $_POST['post_type'];
        if($_POST['post_type']=="shoutout"){

            $post = $_POST['userpost'];
            $query = 'INSERT INTO tblpost (post_content, post_date, post_userID, poster, post_type) VALUES ("'.$post.'", now(), "'.$_SESSION["user_ID"].'", "'.$_SESSION["username"].'", "'.$post_type.'" )';
            $result = mysql_query($query) or mysql_error();
            $tmp_post_ID = mysql_insert_id();
            $type = "post";
            notify($type, $tmp_post_ID);

        }
        if($_POST['post_type']=="story"){
            $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
            $post = $_POST['userpost'];
            $query = 'INSERT INTO tblpost (post_content, post_date, post_userID, poster, post_type, post_title) VALUES ("'.$post.'", now(), "'.$_SESSION["user_ID"].'", "'.$_SESSION["username"].'", "'.$post_type.'", "'.$post_title.'" )';
            $result = mysql_query($query) or mysql_error();
            $tmp_post_ID = mysql_insert_id();
            $type = "post";
            notify($type, $tmp_post_ID);


        }
        if($_POST['post_type']=="image"){
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];
            $user_ID = $_SESSION['user_ID'];
            $post = $_POST['userpost'];
            $img_ID = upload_image($tmp_name,$user_ID);
            $query = 'INSERT INTO tblpost (post_content, post_date, post_userID, poster, post_type, img_ID) VALUES ("'.$post.'", now(), "'.$_SESSION["user_ID"].'", "'.$_SESSION["username"].'", "'.$post_type.'", "'.$img_ID.'" )';
            $result = mysql_query($query) or mysql_error();
            $tmp_post_ID = mysql_insert_id();
            $type = "image";
            notify($type, $tmp_post_ID);


        }
        //header('location:'.curPageURL());
    }

?>
```

Comment: if `e.preventDefault();` isn't working, try `return false;` at the end of your bind. Also, make sure you're bind is actually being called via something like `console.log('derp');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this...

```
$(document).on("submit","#post_form", function (e) {...
```

Or..

```
$("#post_submit_button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //rest of code
});
```

And remove this from your form

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

EDIT **

Based on your updated post

The reason its not working is because you are using multiple forms with one #ID.  Which is illegal

```
                    <form name="post_form" id="post_form" action="" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="story" />
                        <input type="text" name="post_title"/>
                        <textarea name="userpost"></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" name="post_submit" value="post" id="post_submit_button"/>
                    </form>

                    <form name="post_form" id="post_form" action="" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="shoutout" />
                        <input type="text" name="userpost"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="post_submit" value="shout" id="post_submit_button"/>
                    </form>

                    <form name="post_form" id="post_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" name="post_image">
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="image" />
                        <input type="text" name="userpost"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="post_submit" value="upload" id="post_submit_button"/>

                    </form>
```

Just put all the inputs into ONE form and it will work
So based on this info.  Heres how I would do it.

Give all your submit buttons a class...

```
       <input class='form_submit_button' type="submit" value="upload" />
```

Then in your Jquery

```
       $('.form_submit_button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).parent().serialize();

           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php",
            data: form,
            success:function(data){
                //success stuff
            });
        });
```

Comment: I tried this method and removed the onsubmit code. But it didn't really change anything. the ajax function is still not being called and since i removed the onsubmit, it sort of started reloading the page again.

Comment: That shows me that your jquery isnt really working.  Are you sure you've loaded the scripts correctly?  They have to be loaded in the head file before using $(document).  Do a quick test such as $('#post_form').hide(); just to check if jquery is actually working

Comment: yes my other other scripts load perfectly fine. This is the only one thats giving me a real headache.

Comment: You are using multiple ID's for each form.  If you want to submit each piece seperately as ajax.  They all need seperate ID's

Comment: Let me know if my solution works for you. It should.   THe problem you were having was that your code didn't know which #post_form was being referred to because they all had that ID.  This way, you just pull the parent form and submit that

Answer (score 1):

when you pass data from ajax to php

```
data: {variable : variable}, //var variable = $("#post_form").serialize(); and check your variable before pass it
```

and get it in php

```
echo ($_POST['variable']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly. ([**`Example`**](http://jsfiddle.net/up0dhbL9/))

Change your form (as KyleK suggested) to this:

```
<form name="post_form" id="post_form" action="" method="POST">
.....
```

So this narrows down your problem to only one viable option. You either aren't including the jQuery library (possibly a deprecated version), or the way you're testing it is wrong.

Go simple and try this:

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: "post.php",
    data: $("#post_form").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        console . log(data);
    }
});
```

and in your PHP script, just simple do something like this:

```
echo 'uwotm8';
```

To ensure your ajax is running correctly.

Comment: I'm really thinking that the version im using might be the problem. I'm current using 1.11.1, is that fine?

Comment: That should be fine, I used that in the Example I posted above.

Comment: i tried clicking the example but it shows the code i used not yours :/

Comment: I used your exact code, and the whole script works. You need to change your php script and debug from there. Start with `echo json_encode($_POST);` and see if you're getting your data back!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to change your form codes, there are missing double quotes after POST, and no need to add the onsubmit attribute because you already handle that on jQuery.

```
<form name="post_form" id="post_form" action="" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />
      <input type="text" name="userpost"/>
      <input type="submit" name="post_submit" value="post" id="post_submit_button"/>
</form>
```

let me know how you go

Comment: right that mistake was when i was putting in the codes to ask for help haha. The problem wasn't there in my original codes. Still not working though :/

Comment: hahaha ok then, could you please update the question to put your post.php code also?

Comment: I put the jsfiddle over here: http://jsfiddle.net/5omt5won/ and looks all good (jsfiddle throws error because of the php is not there). I'm agree with KyleK, the error is on the jquery it self, because if you already put preventDefault() theres no way your form will reloaded when you click submit. is there any error on console?